# I just got fifteen badges, but I'm not bragging

Tags: support, status-bydesign, badges

I just got fifteen badges, about fifteen minutes ago, split between Announcer, Booster, and one Publicist.  While I do pass links around ... it seems a little strange that I would get so many at one time.  Can anyone check if there was a bug involved (that caused them to be added, or was previously causing them to be skipped), or if someone just linked me like crazy in the last day ...

**[Profile](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/45/c-ross?tab=activity)**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not a bug, [just a change in how these badges are awarded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/118509/151385). You now can get them multiple times and you can get all three for the same question.